# where to place the js_plugins and css_plugins?

Tags: templates

where to place the js_plugins and css_plugins?

I want to create a html/css template.some css files and are coded myself,such as
css/my.css
js/site.js
but sometimes I want to use some existed css or js plugins from other people who had shared on web,such as
1.some plugins only have css,no js needed. (ex:css3_button.css)
2.some plugins have both css and js. (ex:jquery.prettyphoto.js && jquery.prettyphoto.css)
for these plugins ,where should i put them in my template folder?
i do it like this bellow, but i don't think my structure is good enough.

---

index.html 
css 
....my.css 
js   
....my.js 
css_plugin   
....css3_button
........css3_button.css 
js_plugin
....jquery_prettyphoto
........jquery.prettyphoto.css
........jquery.prettyphoto.js

---

how to place these files, to ensure the easy managing in the feature?

Comment: This question should probably be asked at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use static folder, which includes folders for CSS, images and JavaScript. You can also add a folder for your plugins, where each plugin will be in its own folder.

You can replicate your general structure inside each plugin folder, but most plugins come pre-organized, and changing their structure is not always easy.

**example**

```
index.html
static
...js
...css
...img
...plugins
......myFavoritePlugin
.........css
.........js
.........img
......myFavoritePlugin2
.........css
.........js
.........img
```

Keeping the plugin files together makes their maintenance easier, but it affects performance. It is best practice to combine CSS and JavaScript files when deploying on production machines.  You can have best of both worlds if you use build scripts, such as [ant](http://ant.apache.org/)